# How can I get an element to ignore padding if I do not know the parent elements padding?

Tags: html, css

I am using the [bootstrap navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) and am adding custom CSS to it. I am making a button that should fill the navbar for the first 220px. So I want this to ignore the padding for the navbar (or is there a better way), and fill the space with a max/min width of 20px.

This is what I currently have (I want the green box to shift all the way to the lift and fill the top and bottom):

[image]

Here is my code for the above image:

```
.navbar-brand {
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color: #256545;
  float: left;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unset the navbar padding, just set the property to it:

```
padding: 0;
```

Comment: Technically there is `padding: unset;` I think what you mean is remove padding.

Answer (score 0):

If the padding is applied to navbar-brand then set the padding to Zero.

```
.navbar-brand{
  padding:0;
}
```

else assign the padding to the parent class